# Getting error to: MySQL stored procedure with parameters in Access frontend via VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Mysql database has parameterized stored procedure (insert statement) that makes multiple date list with 1 years intervals from two date range like below:

```
autoid  id  tenant_id   ag_id   interval_start  interval_end    rate
10       1     28         1       24/07/2016    23/07/2017        95
11       2     28         1       24/07/2017    23/07/2018       105
12       3     28         1       24/07/2018    23/07/2019       115
```

I' trying to call the procedure from my Access frontend with vba- code below:

**Single row insert statment**

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tid, int_r, inc_r As Long
Dim sdate, edate As Date
Dim strConn, strServer As String

strServer = "192.168.20.2"
strConn = "ODBC;MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver;UID=admin;PORT=3306;DATABASE=tenant_db;PASSWORD=1DBServer;SERVER=" & strServer & ";FILEDSN=C:\Users\abzalali\Dropbox\tenant_db\tenant_db.dsn;"

tid = Me.tenant_id
int_r = Me.initial_rate
inc_r = Me.increase_rate
sdate = Format(Me.startdate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
edate = Format(Me.enddate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = strConn
    .CommandText = "CALL make_intervals_v2(" & tid & ", " & int_r & ", " & inc_r & ",  '" & sdate & "', '" & edate & "')"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End With

MsgBox ("Done")
Me.Refresh

Set cmd = Nothing
```

Procedure run with this code nicely, but insert only first row. After that I added the loop for total recordset like below:

**Multiple row insert statment**

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tid, int_r, inc_r As Long
Dim sdate, edate As Date
Dim strConn, strServer As String

strServer = "192.168.20.2"
strConn = "ODBC;MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver;UID=admin;PORT=3306;DATABASE=tenant_db;PASSWORD=1DBServer;SERVER=" & strServer & ";FILEDSN=C:\Users\abzalali\Dropbox\tenant_db\tenant_db.dsn;"

tid = Me.tenant_id
int_r = Me.initial_rate
inc_r = Me.increase_rate
sdate = Format(Me.startdate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
edate = Format(Me.enddate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = strConn
    .CommandText = "CALL make_intervals_v2(" & tid & ", " & int_r & ", " & inc_r & ",  '" & sdate & "', '" & edate & "')"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
     Set rst=.Execute
End With

Do Until rst.EOF
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox ("Done")
Me.Refresh

Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Finally I'm getting error:

[image]

Don't know what I missed actually.

**Here is my actual stored procedure:**

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE make_intervals_v2 @@
CREATE PROCEDURE tenant_db.make_intervals_v2
(IN `t_id` INT, IN `InitRate` INT, IN `IncrRate` INT, IN `dateStart` DATE, IN `dateEnd` DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE unitval VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE intval INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE thisDate,nextDate DATE;
    DECLARE rate DECIMAL;
    DECLARE ag_id INT;



DECLARE l_ID integer;
DECLARE l_startdate,l_enddate DATE;
DECLARE l_ag_id integer;
DECLARE theCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT tenant_id, dateStart, dateEnd, 1 FROM tbl_tenant_basic_info WHERE active=1 AND tenant_id=t_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

SET unitval='YEAR';
SET intval=1;

drop temporary table if exists year_intervals2;
create temporary table year_intervals2
(   id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    tenant_id INT NOT NULL,
    ag_id INT NOT NULL,
    interval_start DATE NOT NULL,
    interval_end DATE NOT NULL,
    rate DECIMAL
);

OPEN theCursor;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH theCursor INTO l_ID,l_startdate,l_enddate, l_ag_id;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    set thisDate = l_startdate;
    set ag_id= l_ag_id;
    set rate = InitRate;

    repeat
      select
         case unitval
            when 'MICROSECOND' then timestampadd(MICROSECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'SECOND'      then timestampadd(SECOND, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MINUTE'      then timestampadd(MINUTE, intval, thisDate)
            when 'HOUR'        then timestampadd(HOUR, intval, thisDate)
            when 'DAY'         then timestampadd(DAY, intval, thisDate)
            when 'WEEK'        then timestampadd(WEEK, intval, thisDate)
            when 'MONTH'       then timestampadd(MONTH, intval, thisDate)
            when 'QUARTER'     then timestampadd(QUARTER, intval, thisDate)
            when 'YEAR'        then timestampadd(YEAR, intval, thisDate)
         end into nextDate;

        insert into year_intervals2 (tenant_id,interval_start,interval_end, rate, ag_id) select l_ID,thisDate, date_add(nextDate,INTERVAL -1 DAY), rate, ag_id;
      set thisDate = nextDate;
      set rate = rate+IncrRate;
    until thisDate >= l_enddate 
    end repeat;
END LOOP;
insert into tbl_agreement_years (id, tenant_id, ag_id, interval_start,interval_end, rate) 
select * from year_intervals2;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: At which line are you getting that error?

Comment: Do Until rst.EOF

Comment: Is your stored procedure returning a result set?

Comment: don't know. could you please help me, how to to see the return?

Comment: You haven't provided us with the actual stored procedure, so I can't help you with it.

Comment: wait, i'm going to edit post to view actual sp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152749/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-erik-von-asmuth).

Answer (score 0):

You must add a connection to DB

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

...

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn  

...

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn

    ...

    Set rst=.Execute
End With
```

*Edit 1*: Add extra check to recordset loop

```
If rst.State= adStateOpen then
    Do Until rst.EOF
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

*Edit 2*: About the "single row insert statement" problem:

This line of stored procedure catches all `select|fetch ... into ...` statements:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
```

You have two of them in `read_loop` block, solution:

Change the lines:

```
  select
     case unitval
        when 'MICROSECOND' then timestampadd(MICROSECOND, intval, thisDate)
        when 'SECOND'      then timestampadd(SECOND, intval, thisDate)
        when 'MINUTE'      then timestampadd(MINUTE, intval, thisDate)
        when 'HOUR'        then timestampadd(HOUR, intval, thisDate)
        when 'DAY'         then timestampadd(DAY, intval, thisDate)
        when 'WEEK'        then timestampadd(WEEK, intval, thisDate)
        when 'MONTH'       then timestampadd(MONTH, intval, thisDate)
        when 'QUARTER'     then timestampadd(QUARTER, intval, thisDate)
        when 'YEAR'        then timestampadd(YEAR, intval, thisDate)
     end into nextDate;
```

to:

```
  set nextDate = (select
     case unitval
        when 'MICROSECOND' then timestampadd(MICROSECOND, intval, thisDate)
        when 'SECOND'      then timestampadd(SECOND, intval, thisDate)
        when 'MINUTE'      then timestampadd(MINUTE, intval, thisDate)
        when 'HOUR'        then timestampadd(HOUR, intval, thisDate)
        when 'DAY'         then timestampadd(DAY, intval, thisDate)
        when 'WEEK'        then timestampadd(WEEK, intval, thisDate)
        when 'MONTH'       then timestampadd(MONTH, intval, thisDate)
        when 'QUARTER'     then timestampadd(QUARTER, intval, thisDate)
        when 'YEAR'        then timestampadd(YEAR, intval, thisDate)
     end );
```

Comment: Yes, the error is gone, but still, it returns a single row only. That was fine with my previous ***Single row insert statement***.

Comment: @MirAbzalAli I added a second edit, that solves that problem

Comment: My stored procedure return same when I execute in MySql and after the change, the lines (as you recommended) in SP, also return a single row when I execute via VBA as same as before. I hope problem in VBA site, not MySQL sp. FYI, when I change `.CommandType = adCmdText` to `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` then it's generate another error. Whats the difference between them.